# What happens when defer is called twice on same variable?

Tags: go

What happened when defer called twice when the struct of that method has been changed?

For example:

```
rows := Query(`SELECT FROM whatever`)
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() { 
  // do something
}
rows = Query(`SELECT FROM another`) 
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
  // do something else
}
```

which `rows` when the last `rows.Close()` called?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*It depends on the method receiver **and** on the type of the variable.*

Short answer: if you're using the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package, your deferred [`Rows.Close()`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) methods will properly close both of your `Rows` instances because `Rows.Close()` has *pointer* receiver **and** because [`DB.Query()`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) returns a *pointer* (and so `rows` is a pointer). See reasoning and explanation below.

To avoid confusion, I recommend using different variables and it will be clear what you *want* and what *will be* closed:

```
rows := Query(`SELECT FROM whatever`)
defer rows.Close()
// ...
rows2 := Query(`SELECT FROM whatever`)
defer rows2.Close()
```

---

I'd like to point out an important fact that comes from the deferred function and its parameters being evaluated immedately which is stated in the [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer) blog post and in the [Language Spec: Deferred statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) too:

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and **saved anew** but the actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the reverse order they were deferred.

If variable is not a pointer: *You will observe different results when calling a method deferred, depending if the method has a pointer receiver.*
If variable is a pointer, you will see always the "desired" result.

See this example:

```
type X struct {
    S string
}

func (x X) Close() {
    fmt.Println("Value-Closing", x.S)
}

func (x *X) CloseP() {
    fmt.Println("Pointer-Closing", x.S)
}

func main() {
    x := X{"Value-X First"}
    defer x.Close()
    x = X{"Value-X Second"}
    defer x.Close()

    x2 := X{"Value-X2 First"}
    defer x2.CloseP()
    x2 = X{"Value-X2 Second"}
    defer x2.CloseP()

    xp := &X{"Pointer-X First"}
    defer xp.Close()
    xp = &X{"Pointer-X Second"}
    defer xp.Close()

    xp2 := &X{"Pointer-X2 First"}
    defer xp2.CloseP()
    xp2 = &X{"Pointer-X2 Second"}
    defer xp2.CloseP()
}
```

Output:

```
Pointer-Closing Pointer-X2 Second
Pointer-Closing Pointer-X2 First
Value-Closing Pointer-X Second
Value-Closing Pointer-X First
Pointer-Closing Value-X2 Second
Pointer-Closing Value-X2 Second
Value-Closing Value-X Second
Value-Closing Value-X First
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4eI58LBh6i).

Using a pointer variable the result is always good (as expected).

Using a non-pointer variable and using pointer receiver we see the same printed results (the latest) but if we have value receiver, it prints 2 different results.

**Explanation for non-pointer variable:**

As stated, deferred function including the receiver is evaluated when the `defer` executes. In case of a pointer receiver it will be the **address of the local variable**. So when you assign a new value to it and call another `defer`, the pointer receiver will be again the **same address** of the local variable (just the pointed value is different). So later when the function is executed, both will use the same address twice but the *pointed* value will be the same, the one assigned later.

In case of value receiver, the receiver is a **copy** which is made when the `defer` executed, so if you assign a new value to the variable and call another `defer`, another copy will be made which is different from the previous one.

Comment: I missed that part of the spec. Nice. +1

Comment: How does defer copy Pointer? Just make a new pointer which has same value as `xp` and `xp2`, regradless of `Close()` or `CloseP()`?

Comment: @Hunger Yes, a pointer is just a memory address. When you copy a pointer like `p2 := p`, you just copy the memory address which points to the same object. To copy the _pointed_ object, you would have to _dereference_ the pointer, e.g. `obj2 := *p`.

Answer (score 4):

[Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer) mentions:

> **The arguments to the deferred function (which include the receiver if the function is a method) are evaluated when the defer executes, not when the call executes**.
>
> Besides avoiding worries about variables changing values as the function executes, this means that a single deferred call site can defer multiple function executions

In your case, the defer would reference the second rows instance.
The two deferred functions are executed in LIFO order (as mentioned also in "[Defer, Panic, and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)").

As [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28894103/6309) and [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893586/golang-defer-clarification/28893673?noredirect=1#comment46052483_28893673):

> The 2 deferred `Close()` methods will refer to the **2 distinct Rows values** and both will be properly closed because `rows` is a **pointer**, not a value type.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see, the `rows` always refer to the last one, http://play.golang.org/p/_xzxHnbFSz

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
   A string
}

func (x *X) Close() {
  fmt.Println(x.A)
}

func main() {
  rows := X{`1`}
  defer rows.Close()
  rows = X{`2`}
  defer rows.Close()
}
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

So maybe the best way to preserve the object is to pass it to a function: http://play.golang.org/p/TIMCliUn60

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
    A string
}

func (x *X) Close() {
    fmt.Println(x.A)
}

func main() {
    rows := X{`1`}
    defer func(r X) { r.Close() }(rows)
    rows = X{`2`}
    defer func(r X) { r.Close() }(rows)
}
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Comment: The best way would be to use different variables: `rows := X{"1"}; rows2 := X{"2"}` - much simpler and cleaner. Intent is also clearer that you want to close `rows` and `rows2`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you should be able to just add a block, that way you don't have to worry about thinking of a new variable name, and you don't have to worry about any of the items not being closed:

```
rows := Query(`SELECT FROM whatever`)
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() { 
   // do something
}
{
   rows := Query(`SELECT FROM another`) 
   defer rows.Close()
   for rows.Next() {
      // do something else
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks