# Go-SQL-Driver causing maria-db CPU utilization very high

Tags: go, mariadb, driver, cpu

I had an API that I wrote in python flask for the backend of the website and app, which works fine. I recently learned Go and rewrote the whole API in Go. I expected much lower CPU and memory utilization from Go binary file but MariaDB now almost 99% utilization.

I try to limit max connection, maxtimeout, maxidletime,max...etc all option in GitHub page still the no use. I have the connection as global variable in the code, and I defer `result.close()` after every `db.prepare` and `db.query`. I know Go is much faster than python so it make sense to make more request to server but its only test environment it should cause that much cpu utilization any suggestion on how to deal with MariaDB in golang?

FYI: the original site it working from 2015, it have at least over millon row of data, I can recreate the database using gorm and insert the data again but I really want to just use pure SQL (no ORM thank you).

```golang
func getfulldate(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

    pid := c.FormValue("pid")

    result, err := db.Prepare("select concat(p.firstName, ' ', p.middle, ' ', p.lastName, ' ', p.forthName) as fullname,gender,bID,married,barcode,comment,address,if(p2.phone is null, 0, p2.phone)  as phone,rName,occupation,weight,height,cast(Birthdate as date) as Birthdate from profile p left join (select phID, pID, phone from phonefix group by pID) p2 on p.pID = p2.pID left join (select pID, weight, height from bmifix group by pID) B on p.pID = B.pID, religion r where r.rgID = p.rgID and p.pID = ? ")
    defer result.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"access_token": "wrong"})

    }

    rows, err := result.Query(pid)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"access_token": "wrong"})

    }
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    count := len(columns)
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
    for rows.Next() {
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
        }
        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
        entry := make(map[string]interface{})
        for i, col := range columns {
            var v interface{}
            val := values[i]
            b, ok := val.([]byte)
            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }
            entry[col] = v
        }
        tableData = append(tableData, entry)
    }

    currentTime := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
    result, err = db.Prepare("select viID,state as done,dob from visitfix where  patientID = ?")
    defer result.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"access_token": "wrong"})

    }

    rows, err = result.Query(pid)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{"access_token": "wrong"})

    }
    columns = []string{"viID", "done", "dob"}

    count = len(columns)
    tableDatas := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    values = make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtrs = make([]interface{}, count)
    for rows.Next() {
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {

            valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
        }

        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)

        entry := make(map[string]interface{})

        for i, col := range columns {
            var v interface{}
            val := values[i]

            b, ok := val.([]byte)

            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }
            if i == 2 {
                var state string
                format := "2006-1-2"

                datea, err := time.Parse(format, string(b))
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                mydate := datea.Format("2006-01-02")
                if mydate == currentTime {
                    state = "today"
                }
                if mydate < currentTime {
                    state = "older"
                }
                if mydate > currentTime {
                    state = "newer"
                }

                entry["state"] = state

            }

            entry[col] = v
        }

        tableDatas = append(tableDatas, entry)
    }
    alldata := [][]map[string]interface{}{tableData, tableDatas}
    dat, err := json.Marshal(alldata)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return c.SendString(string(dat))
}
```

Comment: Without some code (ideally a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) its going to be difficult for us to help. There are a lot of things you could be doing (e.g. running a query in a tight loop) that will put load on the database server. I'd suggest commenting out all calls to functions that access the database and then re-enabling them one by one until the issue surfaces.

Comment: added a function to see if I do anything wrong this one is most complex one I wrote

Comment: Can't see anything obvious that would cause a performance issue. You could call `Close` on the first `Stmt`/`Rows` when that query is done but the [`defer` should do this when the function exits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28894103/11810946). Ideally check for errors as shown in [this example](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#example-DB.QueryContext) and only `defer` after the error check (otherwise the `Stmt`/`Rows` could be `nil`). The Prepare provides no real advantage here (just use [`Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Query)).

Comment: I dont have error not sure if I do bad practice, in pyhon I used oop which made thing so much eaiser, but as far as go process it have almost 0 cpu usage and barely  taking any ram but mariadb process get piling in short while it take whole cpu and ram full, it feel it keep requesting without wait, as for prepare it doing prepared statement should it be better than just query? I doubt it cause a big amount  of request

Comment: My comment was really just just general suggestions; I understand your issue but cannot see how the code you provided would cause it (which is why I requested a *reproducible* example; understand that this can be difficult to produce but it's hard to help without one). `Prepare` is helpful if you want to run the same query multiple times with different parameters, but as you are only using the `Stmt` once it really just complicates your code (you could also simplify the way you `Scan` but it's unlikely to impact performance).

Answer (score 0):

The go process in itself should not have any other effect on (any) database as any other language barring better driver implementations for retrieving the row data (cursor implementation of MySQL was (and might still be) broken).

As for the cursor usage: This can spread the load over a longer time but you would need a serious amount of data to notice a difference between driver implementations and languages. Compiled languages will be able to put a higher load on the db at that point in time. But again: This would be rare.

The primary candidate to look at here, is most likely indexing: You are querying:

```
    result, err := db.Prepare(`select concat(p.firstName, ' ', p.middle, ' ', p.lastName, ' ', p.forthName) 
as fullname,gender,bID,married,barcode,comment,address,if(p2.phone is null, 0, p2.phone)  
as phone,rName,occupation,weight,height,cast(Birthdate as date) as Birthdate 
from profile p 
left join (select phID, pID, phone from phonefix group by pID) p2 on p.pID = p2.pID 
left join (select pID, weight, height from bmifix group by pID) B on p.pID = B.pID, religion r 
where r.rgID = p.rgID and p.pID = ? `)
```

You want to have indexes on p.pID, r.rgID and p.rgID.
Then also the group by on pID in the left joins might be executed in a suboptimal fashion (run an explain and check the execution plan).

An improvement could be to remove the group by statements: You don't have a group by function, so no use for the group by in the left joins:

```
    result, err := db.Prepare(`select concat(p.firstName, ' ', p.middle, ' ', p.lastName, ' ', p.forthName) 
as fullname,gender,bID,married,barcode,comment,address,if(p2.phone is null, 0, p2.phone)  
as phone,rName,occupation,weight,height,cast(Birthdate as date) as Birthdate 
from profile p 
left join (select phID, pID, phone from phonefix) p2 on p.pID = p2.pID 
left join (select pID, weight, height from bmifix) B on p.pID = B.pID
left join religion r 
where r.rgID = p.rgID and p.pID = ? `)
```

Since you are always retrieving a single pID, and that seems to be a unique record, the following might even be better (can not test: Don't have your DB :)): If possible go to inner joins: That should outperform a left join

Comment: Thank you well mysql quries aside I do have constaint and indexes, I have same site working with flask with same front end client, so its not  the quries , broken cursor its possible  I kinda guess it but I was hoping I was doing something wrong  some one show me a way in python using oop having a global  object for the database and calling curser in each function  was the solution I was hoping for similar  approaches here